# Suggestions how to break up projects with @XmlSeeAlso limiting me

Tags: jaxb

I'd like to start breaking apart a large domain project into various smaller sub projects. The issue is that I have an external project that has some code that needs to unmarshal some xml into a top level base class that all the subprojects can share as a common base. This would be fine, except that I will need an @XmlSeeAlso on the base class that would include every possible subclass (so it seems.) This seems to make it impossible for me to break up the projects in the way I planned.
For example, using animals just for illustration.
Without the XmlSeeAlso on Animal defining the subclasses, I'm pretty much stuck.

```
//Core project jar
public abstract class Animal {
}

//Mammals jar
@XmlSeeAlso({ Dog.class, Cat.class})
public abstract class Mammal extends Animal {
}

//Birds jar
@XmlSeeAlso({ Sparrow.class, Hawk.class})
public abstract class Bird extends Animal {
}


//Third party jar 

//use Bird or Mammal xml
input = new ByteArrayInputStream(birdXml.getBytes());
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Animal.class);
u = jc.createUnmarshaller();

//return Animal - FAILS since Animal would need the XmlSeeAlso of subclasses
Animal animal = (Animal)u.unmarshal(input);
```

Comment: side note, I'm not locked into having to use JAXB, but it's what we have currently.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize that JAXBContext.newInstance can take an array of classes. So in my third party jar I just need to load them all into some common Array and pass them in there to the newInstance method ... JAXBContext.newInstance(myClassesArray);